# Execute certain function on GET request

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am currently designing a plugin which will export some data in admin panel, only when a GET parameter `export=data` is passed. In normal PHP it will do something like:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_GET['export']) && ($_GET['export']=='data')){
 abc(); //Execute this function on GET request
}

function abc(){
 //function data
}
?>
```

Now I want the same thing to happen in my plugin in admin area, assuming the slug of my plugin is '_my-plugin'. So  basically I would like to call the function when this URL is visited:
`http://myblogaddress.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=_my-plugin&export=data`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One of the earlier hooks that is aware of the page (I think) is `load-{$slug}`:

```
add_action( 'load-_my-plugin', 'wpse143915_maybe_trigger_export' );
function wpse143915_maybe_trigger_export(){
    if( isset( $_GET['export'] ) && ( $_GET['export'] == 'data' ) ){
        //...
    }
}
```

If you want to find out what your page slug is, checkout this plug-in by [Kaiser](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/385/kaiser): https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/current-admin-info

But personally, I wouldn't bother waiting for the (admin) screen to be initalised. Just send them to `admin-post.php?action=myprefix-export`, and then you know when that url is hit:

```
add_action( 'admin_post_myprefix-export', 'wpse143915_initiate_export' );
function wpse143915_initiate_export(){
   //Any security / validation checks

   //... export data...
}
```